# BizTalk not picking up messages from Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, biztalk, azureservicebus

After setting up Azure Service Bus and a receive port on already running BizTalk system, I would suggest that the messages would be correctly picked up and processed, but that is not happening.
I have set up SB-Messaging adapter following these steps: [SB-Messaging Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/sb-messaging-adapter)

I have managed to connect to the service bus using Service Bus Explorer - I can retrieve and send messages, but the BizTalk application is not picking anything up. I read somewhere that we need to open ports 9350 to 9354 for this to work, but I need to be 100% sure so that the network team can open these ports.

Is there maybe something that I need to enable/disable for this to work?
What about namespace for brokered message properties?
Is that somehow relevant?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: any errors in event logs? warnings?

Comment: Nothing related to BizTalk application. Got some SQLSERVERAGENT errors, but that is unrelated... Still haven't tested it, but could it be that SB Messaging adapter uses ports 9350 to 9354 instead 443? Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the port range here: [Microsoft.ServiceBus  ConnectivityMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#microsoft_servicebus_connectivitymode)

It specifies that:

> TCP mode. Listeners create TCP connections to the Service Bus service
>   to a destination port in the range 9350 to 9354.

Now I assume the adapter works over `TCP` as this is the default as specified by the docs:

> the system will choose TCP by default

So it's probably best to open up that 9350 to 9354 port range.

Comment: Thanks! Since I am not really familiar with network, do you know if outbound AND inbound traffic need to be enabled?

Comment: @ddelic it's only outbound since you're initiating the connection.

Comment: @ddelic  Did the above answer resolve your question?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it and connection was successful.  Ty @r3verse